# Is there any way to identify what is triggering the select2 closing event?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

Is there any way to identify what is triggering the select2:closing event handler?

More specifically, I want to be able to identify if the closing event was triggered because

1. The user selected a value in the dropdown
2. The user clicked on an area outside of the dropdown
3. The user clicked on the select element ( Which is responsible for displaying the dropdown for the second time without selecting an option in the dropdown)

Based on what I have found, the event only contains information about the target select2 that it is affecting and doesn't have any information about the event that triggered it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a single event, use a different event depending on what you want to know.  You can always combine these into a single event handler.

From [Select2 Events](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events%5D)

1. Used selected a value: `select2:select`

> Triggered whenever a result is selected

2. User clicked on an area outside the dropdown `select2:close`

> Triggered whenever the dropdown is closed

3. User clicked on select again: `select2:opening` or `select2:open`

> `select2:opening` Triggered before the dropdown is opened
>
> `select2:open`    Triggered whenever the dropdown is opened (*has been opened*)

you would then need to check if a value has already been selected, but there's never a difference between a value pre-selected (on load, when the html is rendered) and a value that the user had previously selected.  To know if it's a "second time" (rather than just opening with a value selected) you would also have to record that the dropdown was opened for a "first time".

4. (bonus) User clicked on a selected value (for the second time) `select2:unselect`

> Triggered whenever a selection is removed

---

The exact use-case for (3) will determine whether to use `select2:opening` (before it's been opened) or `select2:open` (after it's been opened)

Here's an example that only allows the user to open the drop down twice - after that it's blocked from being opened:

```js
$('.select2').select2();

$(document).on('select2:opening', function(event) {

  // get the open count from "this" select
  // so each select has its own count
  var openCount = $(this).data("opencount") || 0;

  // check if this is the "third" time (allow it to be opened twice)
  // could just as easily use ||1 above or >0 for "second time"
  if (openCount > 1)
    return false;

  // store on "this" select the open count
  $(this).data("opencount", ++openCount);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="select2" multiple>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Point 3 actually refers to the situation where the user clicks on the 'select element' (which triggers the displaying of the dropdown) after having clicked on it before and not selecting a previously selected value. Is there an event to capture this sequence of events?

Comment: omg... I spent hours trying to find a 'hack' that would help me differentiate scenario 3 from the others to no avail but I think this would work!

Will be attempting to use a variable to record if its the 1st/2nd time the user is triggering the select2:open event and checking for this value in the select2:close event that is triggered when the select element is clicked again.

Will try it out the moment I get to office tomorrow and if it works I will definitely mark this as the answer!

Thank you so much <3 Feel much better being able to go to work with a possible solution in mind

Comment: based on your code snippet I have attempted to use your example to achieve my objective of identifying the 3 different scenarios

However I am seemingly unable to differentiate between scenario 2 & 3 because they both trigger select:close without triggering any other events.

Here is a link to the js fiddle I am testing the solution on
https://jsfiddle.net/j0u4k9mc/

Comment: 2 is close, 3 is open - they're very different and don't seem to conflict.    1 and 2 both close - is that what you mean?  It might be easier if you explain your end-goal / use-case of what you're trying to do, just "know when it's closed" isn't an end goal.

Comment: In the js fiddle that i have linked, these two scenarios end up triggering the close event. Scenario 1 => Click on select element => Click on select element again ( It will trigger open event once and close event once instead of two open events)

Comment: Scenario 2 => Click on select element => Click on an area outside of the select element ( It will end up triggering open event once and close event once) which is identical to scenario 1. Is there any way to differentiate between the two?

Comment: Expected Result
Scenario 1) Click on select element => Click on value 
Results 1) Dropdown gets closed

Scenario 2) Click on select element => Click on area outside of select element
Results 2) Dropdown gets closed

Scenario 3)Click on select element => Click on select element
Results 3) Dropdown DOESNT get closed

Scenario 4)Click on select element => Click on select element => CLick on select element
Results 4) Dropdown element gets closed

Comment: To confirm: (1) click select2, it opens, click again (immediately without selecting anything), it closes.   vs (2) click select2, it opens, click somewhere else, it closes.   Did you want to stop one of them? (scenario 1 or 2?)  *edit* your comment above indicates block (1) in this comment - don't close if clicking in the element without selecting anything

Comment: i want to stop 1. The second time you click the select 2( it should display the keyboard but that is not needed for this test case), it should only close the drop down the third time the select element is clicked. Scenario 2 should close it upon clicking somewhere else

Comment: There's no distinction between clicking outside and clicking an open dropdown (without selecting anything).  That's how a `select` [works](https://jsfiddle.net/xozuqLc6/), so that's how *select2* works.   I guess you'd have to listen for a click event that doesn't fire select2:select, probably need to inspect select2 source to see how it decides to close the dropdown.

Comment: damn... finding a way to differentiate between these events has got me stuck for so long. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: There's `$(event.target).select2("hasFocus")` - but looks like it's not set in time - ie still has focus when clicking out.  There's a `blur` event, but I can't (quickly) determine which element it first on (not the original select and doesn't bubble), then there's `focusout` which does indicate (event.relatedTarget == null), but fires after the closing event.   So might be possible to use that, but would be messy https://jsfiddle.net/xozuqLc6/1/